# ElasticSearch aggregation shows unexpected result for SUM

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-painless

Trying to apply sum aggregation in ES 7.14 and get unexpected result

**1. prepare dataset**

```
$cat products.json
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"productId": 10,"shopId": 45,"prices": {"retailPrice": 525000000.02,"sumRetailPrice": 5250000000.2},"count": 10}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"productId": 10,"shopId": 48,"prices": {"retailPrice": 26250000004,"sumRetailPrice": 5250000000.8},"count": 20}
```

**2. bulk insert**

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/25products/_bulk -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" --data-binary  @./products.json
```

**3. view mapping**

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/25products/_mapping?pretty"
{
  "25products" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "count" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "prices" : {
          "properties" : {
            "retailPrice" : {
              "type" : "float"
            },
            "sumRetailPrice" : {
              "type" : "float"
            }
          }
        },
        "productId" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "shopId" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**4. Sum field "prices.sumRetailPrice" in Painless**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:9200/25products/_search?pretty' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"aggs": {"sumSupplyPrice": {
    "sum": {"script": {
        "source": "(!doc.containsKey('\''prices.sumRetailPrice'\'') ? 0 : (doc['\''prices.sumRetailPrice'\''].size() == 0 ? 0: doc['\''prices.sumRetailPrice'\''].value))"
        }}
    }},
"query": {"bool": {
    "filter": [
        {"terms": {"shopId": [45]}},
        {"terms": {"productId": [10]}}
    ]
    }},
"from": 0, "size": 10
}'
```

result is

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "25products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "productId" : 10,
          "shopId" : 45,
          "prices" : {
            "retailPrice" : 5.2500000002E8,
            "sumRetailPrice" : 5.2500000002E9
          },
          "count" : 10
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "sumSupplyPrice" : {
      "value" : 5.249999872E9
    }
  }
}
```

**4. Expectation**
as well as I have a single record, expecting to have the same value as *sumRetailPrice*

```
"aggregations" : {
    "sumSupplyPrice" : {
      "value" : **5.2500000002E9**
    }
  }
```

But, actual result is not as expected.

```
"aggregations" : {
    "sumSupplyPrice" : {
      "value" : **5.249999872E9**
    }
  }
```

Where am I wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you use a script for summing `prices.sumRetailPrice` and not simply referencing the field?

Comment: actually I have few type of prices already summed before insert
Like sumRetailPriceActiveGoods, sumRetailPriceParkedGoods, sumRetailPriceFrozenGoods

And then I have to sum different type of prices for logical groups of goods, like
all goods (frozen +parked + active)
inactive (parked + active)
etc..

Comment: Why not summing them up into another field then since those sums will never change? it makes no sense to compute something dynamically out of static values

Comment: ok, I can collect result of (frozen +parked + active) = to another field, it is not a problem. Still I have to sum those static values up to filter conditions